# Different Resource Available Hours

Tags: team-management

I am trying to calculate resource utilization with resources spread across Europe and America. The daily availability of resources in Europe would be 7 hours and USA resource availability would be 8 hours a day. How do we calculate combined resource utilization average in this scenario?

An example scenario has been attached. We generally calculate totalfilledhours/totalavailable hours but in this scenario the total available hours would be different by region. Please advise.[image: Resource utilization example]

Comment: You can just sum filled hours and divide by sum of available hours. Alternatively, you might compute utilization independently per region and compute an average. For 0% and 100% utilization, the results are the same, between those extremes you have slight differences which are completely overwhelmed by the meaninglessness of the resulting numbers. By the way, it's people you're dealing with, not machines. Their performance varies, and 100% utilization is a certain method to reduce quality and ultimately throughput. Not a desirable goal.

Comment: Why are you using the word "resources" instead of "people"?